# Getting error while creating a File Upload item in MS Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business, microsoft-forms

I see this error while creating a "File Upload" item in my Microsoft Forms. The file will be uploaded to my Onedrive account. I went in to my Sharepoint Site Collection Features and deactivated the Limited-access user permission lockdown mode, still getting the same error.

Could someone please help me fix this issue? Thanks!

[image]
...
[image]